# Handling Back button in Parent Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have my main activity which contains 2 fragments:

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentOne.OnFragmentOneInteractionListener, FragmentTwo.OnFragmentTwoInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            FragmentOne fragmentOne = new FragmentOne ();

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentOne ).commit();


        }

    }
```

This activity initially display fragment one.

Fragment one has a button which listens and when clicked it will replace itself with fragment two. When the button is clicked the interface in fragment one gets

```
//Main acitivty has this method which is a a method the interface in fragment one requires
@Override
    public void goToFragmentTwo() {

        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
         FragmentTwo fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo ();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentTwo );
        transaction.addToBackStack(FragmentTwo.BACKSTACK_TAG);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

If the android back button or the back button in the toolbar gets called the fragments need to have a confirm dialog which asks are you sure you want to leave. If Ok then I have a second activity called the HomeActivity (this activity is the parent activity of MainActivity) which it needs to go to, or if cancel it needs to just close the dialog and stay in the current fragment.

So in the MainActivity I have overrode the onBackPressed method which displays a :

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

```
    builder.setMessage("Do you want to leave? ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

I am experiencing two problems with this code:

1) Pressing the back button in the toolbar doesn't display a dialog
2) The dialog's OK and Cancel features are not working correctly.

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is I have a HomeActivity which has a button to navigate to the MainActivity. When the MainActivity gets called I will start a workflow where each fragment is a section of that workflow. If the back button is pressed this workflow needs to be discarded and the user should be returned back to the HomeActivty.

Comment: are you using a custom toolbar layout? in fragment? instead of using the activity's toolbar.

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I am not sure? When I created the activities and made the MainActivity a child of the HomeActivity a toolbar was automatically given to me. I am simply using this toolbar. I have no actual toolbar view anywhere in my code.

Comment: try overWrite the `onBackPressed` in HomeActivity...

Comment: @rafsanahmad007 I have moved it from activities, but no no dialog comes up at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i am assuming you are using ActionBar.

Try adding this in your activity:

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage("Do you want to leave? ");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should make your toolbar back button call onBackPressed() from your activity, so they both share the same functionality.

See onSupportNavegationUp() in the main activity.

2) Have your Main Activity control what happens with the fragment, but let the fragments handle any back press if they must.

I hope this is of use to you.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.johnurrutia.so_43172788">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.johnurrutia.so_43172788.MainActivity">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolBar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGoFrag2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go To Fragment TWO" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goToFragmentOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Go To Fragment One" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements FragmentOne.OnFragmentOneInteractionListener, FragmentTwo.OnFragmentTwoInteractionListener {

    public static final int FRAGMENT_ONE = 0;
    public static final int FRAGMENT_TWO = 1;

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private FragmentOne fragmentOne;
    private FragmentTwo fragmentTwo;

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
    private int currentFragment = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            fragmentOne = new FragmentOne();
            fragmentTwo = new FragmentTwo();
            fragments.add(FRAGMENT_ONE, fragmentOne);
            fragments.add(FRAGMENT_TWO, fragmentTwo);

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentOne,"FRAGMENT_ONE")
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentTwo, "FRAGMENT_TWO")
                    .hide(fragmentTwo)
                    .show(fragmentOne)
                    .commit();
        }

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        boolean fragmentProcessedTheEvent = ( (BackButtonListener) fragments.get(currentFragment)).onBackPressed();
        if(!fragmentProcessedTheEvent) {
            //The event is for Main Activity to exit
            showActivityExitDialog();
        }
    }

    public void showActivityExitDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to leave? ");
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    private void switchToFragment(int pos) {
        if (currentFragment != pos) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .hide(fragments.get(currentFragment))
                    .show(fragments.get(pos))
                    .commit();
            currentFragment = pos;
        }
    }

    public void goToFragmentTwo(){
        switchToFragment(FRAGMENT_TWO);
    }

    public void goToFragmentOne(){
        switchToFragment(FRAGMENT_ONE);
    }
}
```

FragmentOne.java

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment implements BackButtonListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

        Button goToFragmentTwoBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnGoFrag2);
        goToFragmentTwoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ( (OnFragmentOneInteractionListener) getActivity() ).goToFragmentTwo();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public interface OnFragmentOneInteractionListener{
        public void goToFragmentTwo();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        /*
        *  if(fragment_has_any_use_for_back_press){
        *      process_it_here();
        *      return EVENT_PROCESSED;
        *  }
        *
        * */

        return EVENT_IGNORED;
    }
}
```

FragmentTwo.java

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment implements BackButtonListener{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        Button goToFragmentTwoBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.goToFragmentOne);
        goToFragmentTwoBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ( (FragmentTwo.OnFragmentTwoInteractionListener) getActivity() ).goToFragmentOne();
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed() {
        /*
        *  if(fragment_has_any_use_for_back_press){
        *      process_it_here();
        *      return EVENT_PROCESSED;
        *  }
        *
        * */

        return EVENT_IGNORED;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentTwoInteractionListener{
        public void goToFragmentOne();
    }
}
```

BackButtonListener.java

```
public interface BackButtonListener {
    public static final boolean EVENT_PROCESSED = true;
    public static final boolean EVENT_IGNORED = false;
    public boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am quite new to android and have some questions. 1) Where or how do I make the toolbar call this method? 2) How do I foreward a call from the activtities' onBackPressed method to a Fragment (which method to call)?